How to create a new ip route in Rust?
I'm trying to do the following in Rust:
ip route add <ip_address> dev <device_name>

I've found the rtnetlink library that seems to have this functionality through the RouteAddRequest struct in Rust. However, I'm not quite sure how to set the device for that.
Note: I'm new to Rust and don't know a lot about the netlink protocol.

Did you see this example ? It shows how to add a route specifying the interface

Hey @harmic, thanks! I hadn't seen those. They didn't work for me, but the one from a previous commit did (https://github.com/rust-netlink/rtnetlink/blob/6d77e01b8decc4a4bcae5a1c490203852e555fea/examples/add_route_pref_src.rs).
I'm just not sure what would be the destination and prefix in this case. Would you know if ip route add has any defaults for these?
My understanding is that the command equivalent to what I'm trying to do only receives a destination (ip_address) and a device name.
